# NAT and UDP replies by default

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, udp

If I send UDP packets from Machine A with local port M behind a NAT to Machine B's port N, where Machine B is outside the NAT (elsewhere on the Internet), can I reasonably expect that NAT would pass UDP packets received from Machine B (local port N) back to port M on Machine A, without requiring manual port forwarding on the NAT?

I know the answer would be yes if the router is configured to preserve source ports when possible, and that source port is not in use. But my question is more about probability. Most of the time, do most routers have this configuration on by default or not.

In other words if I make a multiplayer game to use UDP, would it be reasonable to expect that it would work on most people's computers (even tough at their homes most people have routers) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS queries behave just like that: UDP packet on port 53 from your computer to the Internet and back again.

Nevertheless it is only in a "reply-response" thing and the response should not be delayed in time, or it will be lost.

In a game, there will be a lot of packets from the server to the clients. You will be needing to implement a constant polling of server status to make it work. Remember: one question - one answer.

Technically, you could implement your game that way without needing to open ports on routers

Comment: Well if the game is fps, the performance should be better because it wouldn't have to worry if the packets are actually received properly. It will just keep sending more packets with new coordinates, so even if there is a missed packet it is all fine. However with tcp/ip if a packet fails, there is a lag because it resets all packets from 1, than 2, than 4 , etc. At least that is my understanding. Correct me if I am wrong. Of course the game will run on 2 protocols tcp and udp for things it cares about the 100% delivery and things it doesn't

Comment: It would be better performance if there is no need to do polling, but it should be enough for most games.

Comment: Lets say in the game someone moves. My idea is to have each 2-20 ms sending information to the server with the the new coordinates, at the same time, the server will reply with information what all other players have moved also and will confirm that the move is done successfully. In this case even if a packet or 2 miss, it is all completely fine. There will be also parallel tcp connection to make sure it is all alive, if the TCP connection dies, everyone gets notified that someone is disconnected. But for the fast back and forth  movement, that should be faster with UDP than tcp or so it seem.

Comment: Never considered TCP for game updates. Use UDP and forget about opening ports on routers

Comment: Well my original question is if most routers will be fine with the addressing translation when the udp packets come from the server to the client. The answer should be more like yes or no for most of the time on most routers.

Comment: I have already said that it will work without doing anything. Even I provided the DNS example. But if you insist: YES IT WILL WORK , but with the already mentioned limitations